# How to check if a string already exists and if it does add +1 at the end?

Tags: php, mysql, string

Let's say i check if

```
$strig = "red-hot-chili-peppers-californication";
```

already exists in my database:

```
$query = dbquery("SELECT * FROM `videos` WHERE `slug` = '".$strig."';");
$checkvideo = dbrows($query);
if($checkvideo == 1){

// the code to be executed to rename $strig
// to "red-hot-chili-peppers-californication-2"
// it would be great to work even if $string is defined as 
// "red-hot-chili-peppers-californication-2"  and 
// rename $string to "red-hot-chili-peppers-californication-3"  and so on...

}
```

I want to do this to create unique slugs for a more friendly url structure.

Thanks.

Comment: What does `dbrows($query)` do here?

Comment: that is just a mysql_num_rows function

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I can offer you the source of [Codeigniter's](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/string_helper.html) `increment_string()` function:

```
/**
 * CodeIgniter String Helpers
 *
 * @package     CodeIgniter
 * @subpackage  Helpers
 * @category    Helpers
 * @author      ExpressionEngine Dev Team
 * @link        http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/string_helper.html
 */

/**
 * Add's _1 to a string or increment the ending number to allow _2, _3, etc
 *
 * @param   string  $str  required
 * @param   string  $separator  What should the duplicate number be appended with
 * @param   string  $first  Which number should be used for the first dupe increment
 * @return  string
 */
function increment_string($str, $separator = '_', $first = 1)
{
    preg_match('/(.+)'.$separator.'([0-9]+)$/', $str, $match);

    return isset($match[2]) ? $match[1].$separator.($match[2] + 1) : $str.$separator.$first;
}
```

> Increments a string by appending a number to it or increasing the
>   number. Useful for creating "copies" or a file or duplicating database
>   content which has unique titles or slugs.
>
> **Usage example:**
>
> ```
> echo increment_string('file', '_'); // "file_1"
> echo increment_string('file', '-', 2); // "file-2"
> echo increment_string('file-4'); // "file-5"
> ```

Comment: this seems it does the job (used the second example). thank you very much!

Comment: It feels a bit awkward to just paste code that isn't mine, but glad it works.

Answer (score 2):

```
$str = "some-string-that-might-end-in-a-number";
$strLen = strlen($str);
//check the last character of the string for number
if(intval($str[$strLen-1])>0)
{
    //Now we replace the last number with the number+1
    $newNumber = intval($str[$strLen-1]) +1;
    $str = substr($str, 0, -1).$newNumber;
}
else
{
    //Now we append a number to the end;
    $str .= "-1";
}
```

Of course the limitation of this is that it can only get the last digit.. what if the number was 10?

```
$str = "some-string-that-might-end-in-a-number";
$strLen = strlen($str);

$numberOfDigits = 0;
for($i=$strLen-1; $i>0; $i--)
{
    if(intval($str[$i])==0)
    {
        $numberOfDigits = $strLen-($i-1);
        break;
    }
}

//Now lets do the digit modification
$newNumber = 0;
for($i=1; $i<=$numberOfDigits; $i++)
{
    $newNumber += intval($str[$strLen-$i])*((10*$i)-10));
}
if($newNumber == 0)
{ $newNumber = 1; }

$newStr = "-{$newNumber}";

//Now lets add the new string to the old one
$str = substr($str, 0, ($numberOfDigits*-1)).$newNumber;
```