# Add a number after a string, if it already exists

Tags: php, mysql

I'm working on a script that checks if the url already exists in the database, and if yes adds an additional -1 or -2 etc etc at the end. I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9546732/how-to-check-if-a-string-already-exists-and-if-it-does-add-1-at-the-end) script

But it 'd need to to check it again after adding-1. Since it may be already existing. How can I do that? I tired i this way

```
        $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM posts WHERE url='$url'");   

        while ( $query ) {      

            $result = mysql_fetch_assoc($query);
            $url = $result['url'];
            $urlnew = $result['url'];   
            $oldurl = $url;             
            $first = 1;
            $separator = '-';

            while ( $urlnew == $url ) {

                $url = preg_match('/(.+)'.$separator.'([0-9]+)$/', $urlnew, $match);        

                $urlnew = isset($match[2]) ? $match[1].$separator.($match[2] + 1) : $url.$separator.$first;

                $first++;

            }
        $url = $urlnew;
        }
```

The new code above works just fine. But it checks only once. How can I make it to check untill it dose not exists in the DB?

tried adding a new sql query at the bottom after $url -$urlnew but it only breaks the function.

**EDIT**

Here's the correct script :D

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM posts WHERE url LIKE '%".$url."%'");    

if ( $query ) {

    while ( $result = mysql_fetch_assoc($query) ) {     

        $url = $result['url'];
        $urlnew = $result['url'];           
        $first = 1;
        $separator = '-';


        while ( $urlnew == $url ) {

            preg_match('/(.+)'.$separator.'([0-9]+)$/', $urlnew, $match);       

            $urlnew = isset($match[2]) ? $match[1].$separator.($match[2] + 1) :$url.$separator.$first;

            $first++;   

        }

    }
}                       

$url = $urlnew;
```

Comment: That's an improvement. I removed my downvote.

Comment: `mysql_fetch_assoc` only returns one row.  Is it possible for your query to return more than one row?

Comment: Does `$this->increment_string` work correctly?

Comment: @Rocket Hazmat It dose. but it only checks one url. And not sure how could I make it to check multiple times after adding the number after it.

Comment: @And0r1995, define `$first` before your loop, and then after the last line in your loop, `$first = $first + 1;`

Comment: @Rocket Still doesn't Work

Comment: How does increment_string work? Is it simply adding the separator and number to the end of the string being passed to it? If so, then you're going to have to make sure that you remove the ending from the string before adding the new ending to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is likely vulnerable to [SQL Injection](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php). You should consider using [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) instead.

Here's an example of how you could do so:

```
$url = 'www.example.com';
$i = 0;
$max_duplicates = 100;

$query = $pdo->prepare('SELECT COUNT(id) count FROM urls WHERE url=?');
while ($i++ < $max_duplicates) {
  $result = $query->execute($url);

  if (!$result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ)->count)
    break;

  if ($i == 1) {
    $url = $url . '-1';
  } else {
    $n = $i > 10 ? 2 : 1;
    $url = substr($url, -$n) . $i;
  }
}
```

Comment: How can I configure this to work with mysql_ queries and functions? Not sure how to work with $pdo

Comment: mysql_ is deprecated and due to be removed in PHP 5.5 (which is currently in the RC release stage). View the attached links for how to work with pdo, or mysqli. MySQLi is almost a drop in replacement when used procedural form.

Comment: I see, thanks for the news. Didn't knew that it'll be dropped.

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I used for my needs

```
function checkLink($link, $counter=1){
    global $connect;
    $newLink = $link;
    do{
        $checkLink = mysqli_query($connect, "SELECT id FROM table WHERE link = '$newLink'");
        if(mysqli_num_rows($checkLink) > 0){
            $newLink = $link.'-'.$counter;
            $counter++;
        } else {
            break;
        }
    } while(1);

    return $newLink;
}

$link = 'www.example.com';
$uniquelink = checkLink($link);
```